# Javascript escaping strings for output and avoid NaN

Tags: javascript, jquery, escaping

Trying to use jquery to output a string that contains a hyphen like so:
`$("#OpsContent").html($("#OpsContent").html() + "<b>" + $(this).text() +

    + ( ( group ) ? " for <u>" + group  + "</u>" : "" )

    + " to</b> " + choices + "<br />");`

Unfortunately if the string "group" contains a hyphen, the output always appears as:
`<b>Set Group Rank<u>NaN</u> to</b> 5`

I can't seem to get the group variable to be correctly interpretted as a string, it seems rather like it is trying to subtract the two halves of the string.  I have tried using `group = group.replace("-", "&#46;");` and `"\-"` before the line in question, but it doesn't help.  Even stranger is the fact that a line immediately after works fine:

`OpsPending[ count ] = "?do=" + String($(this).attr("id"))

                         + "&selection=" + choices

                         + ( ( group ) ? "&group=" + group : "" );`
outputs to the variable perfectly well!

A solution would be to go back and pre-process all the hyphens in the page with php, but that seems unnecessarily complicated: there should be a better way than this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hm, you seem to have an extra `+` in your string concatenation (right before the parenthesized ternary operator), which would cause the part where you are using the ternary operator to be converted from a string to a number since that extra `+` would be interpreted as a unary plus operator, resulting in NaN. Although that doesn't exactly explain your symptons (i.e. it only occuring when `group` has a hyphen, and actually only having `group` appearing as NaN, not the entire ternary expression), I can't see how your code example would work correctly without removing the extra `+` there

Comment: Perfect. I hate when that happens, but you have successfully solved my problem.  Thanks!